# SAPUI5 sap.m.Input - Suggestion values

Tags: input, odata, sapui5, search-suggestion

How do I enable live suggestions with reading from my odata Service for a single cell in my table?

```
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
                template : new sap.m.Input({
                    value : column, // also works, its dynamic
                    textAlign : sap.ui.core.TextAlign.Center,
                    inputType : Text,
                    type : sap.m.InputType.Text,
                    showSuggestion : true,
                    liveChange : function() {
                        if (this.getValue().length > 0) {
                            var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
                            var value = this.getValue();
                            var serviceUrl = "/sap/opu/odata/SAP/XXXX_SRV/SuggestionsSet/?$filter=startswith(Key,'" + value + "')";
                            oModel.loadData(serviceUrl, null, false, "GET", false, false, null);

                            this.destroySuggestionItems();
                            for (var i = 0; i < oModel.oData.d.results.length; i++) {
                                this.addSuggestionItem(new sap.ui.core.Item({
                                    text: oModel.oData.d.results[i].Key,
                                }));
                            } // everything seems fine, but no Suggestion opens..


                        }
                    },
                }),
                visible : true,
            }));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the [explored example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.InputSuggestionsDynamic/preview).
However, in your case the model is an ODataModel, but that does not really matter...
As you can see in the examples's code you can also use

```
showSuggestion="true"
suggest="handleSuggest"
suggestionItems="{/ProductCollection}"
```

In the handler you then do this (copied from the example as well):

```
handleSuggest: function(oEvent) {
    var sTerm = oEvent.getParameter("suggestValue");
    var aFilters = [];
    if (sTerm) {
        aFilters.push(new Filter("Name", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.StartsWith, sTerm));
    }
    oEvent.getSource().getBinding("suggestionItems").filter(aFilters);
}
```

Basically you 
 - create one or more filters
 - get the binding for the **suggestionItems** aggregation
 - call **.filter(...)** on the binding and pass the filter(s)

There is no need to code that stuff manually (i.e. GET request etc.).

Here is a runninh example for you ([run via jsbin](https://jsbin.com/woviyiyiru/edit?html,output)), see below.
In your case all you do is bind to

```
suggestionItems="{path:'/SuggestionSet', templateShareable:false}">
```

In the handleSuggest handler you would then get the the value for the **Key** property of the **SuggestionSet** that belongs to current/corresponding input field in order to instantiate a new Filter. You could get the **Key** from the BindingContext I guess...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>SAPUI5 single file template | nabisoft</title>
        <script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-preload="async"></script>
            <!-- use "sync" or change the code below if you have issues -->

            <!-- XMLView -->
            <script id="myXmlView" type="ui5/xmlview">
                <mvc:View
                    controllerName="MyController"
                    xmlns="sap.m"
                    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
                    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">

                    <Table
                        id="myTable"
                        growing="true"
                        growingThreshold="10"
                        growingScrollToLoad="true"
                        busyIndicatorDelay="0">
                        <columns>
                            <Column>
                                <Text text="Customer ID"/>
                            </Column>
                            <Column>
                                <Text text="Company Name"/>
                            </Column>
                        </columns>
                        <items>
                            <!-- filled via bindItems() in controller -->
                        </items>
                    </Table>

                </mvc:View>
            </script>

            <!-- XML Fragment -->
            <script id="myXMLFragment" type="ui5/fragment">
                <core:FragmentDefinition
                    xmlns="sap.m"
                    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
                    <ColumnListItem type="Active">
                        <cells>
                            <ObjectIdentifier title="{CustomerID}"/>

                            <Input
                                value="{CompanyName}"
                                showSuggestion="true"
                                suggest="handleSuggest"
                                suggestionItems="{path:'/Customers', templateShareable:false}">
                                <suggestionItems>
                                    <core:Item text="{CompanyName}" />
                                </suggestionItems>
                            </Input>

                        </cells>
                    </ColumnListItem>
                </core:FragmentDefinition>
            </script>


        <script>
            sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
                "use strict";

                //### Controller ###
                sap.ui.controller("MyController", {
                    onInit : function () {

                        this.getView().setModel(
                            new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/", {
                                json : true,
                                useBatch : false
                            })
                        );

                        var sPath = "/Customers";
                        var oTable = this.byId("myTable");
                        var oTemplate =  sap.ui.xmlfragment({
                            fragmentContent : jQuery("#myXMLFragment").html()
                        });

                        oTable.bindItems(sPath, oTemplate, null /*oSorter*/, null /*aFilters*/);
                    },
                    handleSuggest: function(oEvent) {
                        var sTerm = oEvent.getParameter("suggestValue");
                        var aFilters = [];
                        if (sTerm) {
                            aFilters.push(new Filter("CompanyName", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.StartsWith, sTerm));
                        }
                        oEvent.getSource().getBinding("suggestionItems").filter(aFilters);
                    }
                });

                //### THE APP: place the XMLView somewhere into DOM ###
                sap.ui.xmlview({
                    viewContent : jQuery("#myXmlView").html()
                }).placeAt("content");

            });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body class="sapUiBody">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: not exactly what I was asking for, I got a lot of cells, each cell has other suggestionItems, this is why I load them dynamically during liveChange with an oData request...

Comment: For each cell I can see your GET request looks the same except a different "value". value is the sTerm in my suggestion. That means you can bind the suggestionItems of your template to "{/SuggestionSet}", right? Why would that not work?

Comment: @zyrex I updated the answer and added a working example. Is that what you are looking for?